# Vim: pattern matching only among the keywords

Tags: c++, vim

In vim, language-wise keywords are defined. I want to find patterns using regular expression only among these language-wise keywords.

My original motivation is highlighting the c++'s member variables, which is usually with an underscore in the end of the word. In the example below, I'd like to highlight only `route_graph_`.

```cpp
auto graph = route_graph_;
auto path = extract_path(route_graph_);
auto local_graph = createLocalGraph();
```

My initial attempt is by `/.*_`, but obviously the result shown below was not what I wanted. But I think if I could search `/.*_` only among the keywords, it is possible to highlight only `route_graph_`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about matching keywords, but you can get there by replacing `.*` with something a little more selective.

- `\<` and `\>` match word boundaries.
- `\w*` matches word characters.

Put them together and you get:

```
/\<\w*_\>
```

Which matches just the desired identifier:

[image: vim screenshot of highlighted matches]

Comment: See `:help \k` for matching keyword characters and `:help \i` for identifier characters.